# What is the difference between an LLC and a PLLC?

Tags: legal, llc

I'm a mobile developer in the state of Florida and I'm currently freelancing through an LLC I setup a couple years ago.  I went to a talk about business startups recently and the term PLLC, or professional limited liability company, was mentioned specifically in reference to computer professionals working by themselves through an LLC.

I don't know much about the PLLC and I'm wondering if this type of company is more suited to the work that I'm doing.  What is the difference between an LLC and a PLLC and which is more suited for a developer working alone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many states do not allow an LLC to be formed for professionals who require a license (e.g. lawyers, engineers, accountants). A PLLC is intended for licensed professionals who require the benefits of an LLC.

> A professional limited liability company (“PLLC”) is a business entity
>   designed for licensed professions, such as lawyers, doctors,
>   architects, engineers, accountants, and chiropractors. While many
>   businesses choose to form a limited liability company (“LLC”) because
>   of the tax, limited liability, and other benefits, states generally
>   don’t allow LLCs for businesses where a license is required. Licensed
>   professionals who want the benefits of an LLC must form a PLLC
>   instead.

http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/what-professional-limited-liability-company.html

Although there is occasionally debate in the computer professional business (eg. the recent editorial in ACM Communications), I am not aware of any jurisdiction which requires software engineers to be licensed in a similar way as, say, a civil engineer. Perhaps your speaker thought it looked better (ie. more "professional"?).